# Trying to get data from an API

Tags: r, api-key, httr, jsonlite

I'm trying to get some appointment data from a practice management software. I have an API key but I have no experience in the area.

I have tried to convert Curl code with little success. The api documentation is here https://github.com/redguava/cliniko-api

I am trying to convert this curl code

```
curl https://api.cliniko.com/v1/appointments \
  -u API_KEY: \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'User-Agent: APP_VENDOR_NAME (APP_VENDOR_EMAIL)'
```

What I've tried: (yes this is from a curl to r converter)

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `Accept` = 'application/json',
  `User-Agent` = 'APP_VENDOR_NAME (APP_VENDOR_EMAIL)'
)

res <- httr::GET(url = 'https://api.cliniko.com/v1/appointments', 
httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), 
httr::authenticate('API_KEY', 'INSERTED MY API KEY'))
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: [1] "Client error: (401) Unauthorized"

Comment: From the API doc, there's no password, you may have  better success with `httr::authenticate('INSERTED MY API KEY',''))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`httr::authenticate`](https://rdrr.io/cran/httr/man/authenticate.html) takes input `username` and `password` in the form `httr::authenticate(username,password)`.

[Curl's authenticate](https://ec.haxx.se/http-auth.html) takes argument `username` and `password` joined by by a `:`, i.e. `username:password`.

In the example from the API documentation the curl command authenticates the `username:password` combination `API_KEY:`. Looking closely, we can see that after the `:` is blank. From this we can determine the username field should be 'API_KEY' and the password field should be ''.

So you should change your curl command to:

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `Accept` = 'application/json',
  `User-Agent` = 'APP_VENDOR_NAME (APP_VENDOR_EMAIL)'
)

res <- httr::GET(url = 'https://api.cliniko.com/v1/appointments', 
httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), 
httr::authenticate('API_KEY', ''))
```

Where `API_KEY` is your provided API key.

Comment: Or quoting from the doc linked int he question "You should provide the Cliniko API Key as the basic auth username. There is no need to provide a password."

Comment: Thank you very much you are 100% spot on. I managed to get it working :)